# Custom pl/sql code to process the IG data on submit instead of the native process

Tags: oracle-apex

[How can I use custom pl/sql code to process insert update the IG data  (which is attached with inner join) on submit instead of the native process in oracle apex Interactive Grid.  If anyone have solution please reply.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0XmK.jpg)

```
SELECT dept.DNAME,
       emp.empno,
       emp.ename,
       emp.job,
       emp.mgr,
       emp.hiredate 
  FROM emp
 INNER JOIN dept ON
   emp.deptno = dept.deptno
```

Answer (score 2):

To update just the emp record (it should be trivial to add code for the dept table) you could use this block.

```
begin
    if :APEX$ROW_STATUS = 'D' then
        -- DELETE the record
        delete from emp
         where empno = :EMPNO;
         
    elsif :APEX$ROW_STATUS = 'U' then
        update emp SET 
               ename = :ENAME,
               job = :JOB,
               mgr = :MGR,
               hiredate = :HIREDATE
         where empno = :EMPNO;
    elsif :APEX$ROW_STATUS = 'C' then
         insert into emp (ename, job, mgr, hiredate) 
          values (:ENAME, :JOB, :MRG, :HIREDATE);
    end if;
end;
```

There are a couple of very complete blogs on this topic, for example here:
https://mikesmithers.wordpress.com/2019/07/23/customizing-dml-in-an-apex-interactive-grid/, make sure to also check the references section at the bottom.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is a link-only answer and if the link dies then the answer has no useful content. It would be better to include sufficient detail in your response so that it is actually an answer in its own right.

Comment: @MTO good point I keep forgetting that links do die eventually :) Updated my answer.