# How to update several rows in a Apex form from and Interactive grid

Tags: oracle-apex, ape

I have and Interactive grid linked to a form referencing this db.
See example column layout with some example data.

[image: example data]

My PK's are Asset and LastBatchDate.

I have the IG linked to the Form with Asset and LastBatchDate.

In my IG when I go to edit a record it pulls up a single record in the form but when I go to **save/update** the record in the form I would like to update all records where last batch date = P7_LastBatchDate and assset = to P7_Asset.
Which in this case is 4 records (in yellow), and I'm updating the two columns (in green) only.

All other columns in the form are read only.

See example of what is expected.
[image: update]

Any help would be appreciated.

Bob

Comment: For the update of a form you can write any pl/sql procedure. Delete the native form update procedure and write your own to update all those rows on submit.

Comment: @KoenLostrie  I have the update sql writen, just looking for some examples on how and where to execute .

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73551999/custom-pl-sql-code-to-process-the-ig-data-on-submit-instead-of-the-native-proces) help ?