# In oracle apex, when I modify the data in interactive grid which has a union query, it gives me ORA-02014 error. How to handle this error?

Tags: oracle-apex, union, interactive-grid, ora-02014

When I try to modify the interactive grid column it gives ORA-02014 error.

In back-end i have used sql query with union in it and also used join to join 3 tables.

I tried in the last couple of days and I expect someone might have the solution.

Answer (score 0):

There might be other options than the one I'm going to suggest - such as

- rewriting query so that you don't join tables, but fetch *lookup* values via functions and then set those columns to *read only* so that updates don't affect them, or
- you could (in Apex) create your own process, such as this one (see "Help" for more sample code), with these settings:

  [image]

---

I prefer creating a view and instead-of trigger which handles updates.

Here's an example; see if it helps.

View that joins some tables and contains `union` (that's what you described):

```
SQL> create or replace view v_emp_dept as
  2  select distinct d.deptno, d.dname, e.empno, e.ename, e.job
  3     from emp e join dept d on e.deptno = d.deptno
  4     where e.deptno = 10
  5  union all
  6  select distinct d.deptno, d.dname, e.empno, e.ename, e.job
  7     from emp e join dept d on e.deptno = d.deptno
  8     where e.deptno = 20;

View created.
```

This is one row:

```
SQL> select * from v_emp_dept where empno = 7369;

    DEPTNO DNAME               EMPNO ENAME      JOB
---------- -------------- ---------- ---------- ---------
        20 RESEARCH             7369 SMITH      CLERK
```

What happens if we try to update it? Fails (not with your error, though, but - it fails):

```
SQL> update v_emp_dept set deptno = 10 where empno = 7369;
update v_emp_dept set deptno = 10 where empno = 7369
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01732: data manipulation operation not legal on this view
```

Instead-of trigger:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger trg_ed
  2    instead of update
  3    on v_emp_dept
  4  begin
  5    update emp e set
  6      e.deptno = :new.deptno
  7      where e.empno = :new.empno;
  8  end;
  9  /

Trigger created.
```

Re-run the same `update` statement:

```
SQL> update v_emp_dept set deptno = 10 where empno = 7369;

1 row updated.
```

Right; now it works and updates value - not in a view (it just reflects that change), but in underlying table:

```
SQL> select * from v_emp_dept where empno = 7369;

    DEPTNO DNAME               EMPNO ENAME      JOB
---------- -------------- ---------- ---------- ---------
        10 ACCOUNTING           7369 SMITH      CLERK

SQL> select deptno from emp where empno = 7369;

    DEPTNO
----------
        10

SQL>
```

Comment: Actually when I use union in a  query then only it gives me this error otherwise it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

There error pretty much says it all. The database engine cannot determine how to update the data from the select query. When the interactive grid is rendered, it will try to do a `SELECT * FROM (<the IG query>) FOR UPDATE` . In your case, this statement is erroring out when you add the union. This is what happening under the hood:

query without union works fine:

```
select * from (
select * from emp where ename = 'KING'
) for update;
```

query with union works cannot be selected for update:

```
select * from (
select * from emp where ename = 'KING'
union all
select * from emp where ename = 'BLAKE'
) for update;
    
Error at line 1/15: ORA-02014: cannot select FOR UPDATE from view with DISTINCT, GROUP BY, etc.
```

Any of the solutions @Littlefoot mentions will could work.

Comment: can u elaborate the first solution with pl/sql code

Comment: There is an example in @LIttlefoots answer - what is not clear about it ? There are many examples online, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73551999/custom-pl-sql-code-to-process-the-ig-data-on-submit-instead-of-the-native-proces) is a stack overflow example.

Comment: Actulally using union I fetch data from different table

Comment: I'm happy to help but... with no sample data and no details about what the expected result is of an update/insert/delete on the IG that is impossible. Your question was about the ORA-02014 error and you got 2 very complete answers. Now you're asking a followup question that only I (and no one else on stack overflow) am notified of. I suggest you post a new question with a proper reproducible case (preferrably on the emp/dept sample dataset - everyone has access to that), details about what behaviour you are seeing and what you are expecting and what you have already tried / where it failed.